# How to set the Border Color of a Flex Spark Button with CSS

Tags: css, apache-flex, flex4, skinning

Is it possible? Or do I need to use Skin architecture? in  I can't found the property border color, so I think I need to create a entire skin customized? Or are there the property accessible by css?

Comment: When rendered in a browser, is the button accessible in CSS? Is there a CSS file?

Comment: Yes, there is a css file, but there are no property to access the border color on spark button, for example. s|Button{ /*What property? */}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think to change the border color is to create a custom skin, and set up the color of rectangles that draw the component. I haven't found  accessors or property to set the color of the spark button border directly.

Answer (score 3):

Create a custom Skin based on the default spark ButtonSkin.
You'll notice a Rect named "border".
The border is actually a gradient, I suggest you to replace it by a SolidColorStroke for now.
Set an id to this stroke

In the updateDisplayList method, add :
strokeId.color = getStyle("borderColor");

now you can use a borderColor property in your CSS file ;)

Comment: Yes, I did it. So CSS don't solve my problem as I thought. Thanks.